# how to test a cronjob execution via server with php

Tags: php, cron

Is there a way to run cronjob via php? but not by open the URL of the script, like if is really executed by the server.

I need this to test my cronjob.php file because if i open the URL of the script everything work, but via server cronjob don't!

For example with the function exec? with what url?

```
<?php echo( exec( ) ); ?>
```

the url of my cronjo is:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/content/**/***/html/app/script2/cronjobs.php
```

Comment: Could you post the cronjob you wrote?

Comment: Use **$.ajax** instead.

Comment: try to test it under the cli  .. the terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cronjob functions when you access it directly from a URL, then, there must be a problem in the way you call the cronjob.

Various things to look into:

- Check the time for which you set the cronjob (every minute ? every hour ?). It may not be executing because the time or configuration is wrong
- Check the environment configuration used by the php CLI (Command Line Interfac): maybe you CLI has different `php.ini` or shell environment variables ! Look for the `php.ini` and the `max_execution_time` value.
- Check that you `cronjobs.php` file can be started as standalone. For example, if you're using a web framewor, usually some other files must be called first
- Check in you php or associated logs for errors !

Once you get your cronjob working, it shouldn’t be accessible from the web, that’s bad practice and vulnerability.

Well, this should start to get you back on track ;)

Comment: thx! i ve figured out what the problem was, and now cron work via server and manually (with a key). the problem was the session_start(), the strange thing is that in the past week cron worked with session_start(), no don't!